# fetching table with child in firebase database gives many instances of same object

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have my API here:

```
 findById(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.db.list('/users').$ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)
    .once('value');
  }
```

And its caller here:

```
 this.usersService.findById(value)
      .then(snap => {
          snap.forEach(e => {
            console.log(e.val());
          });
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      });
```

In my database I have only **2 users** (users the tables not the authenticated ones).

When I run my app (my Angular 4 page) I see a lot of the same object logged:

Here:

[image]

My question is why is there so many instances of the same object (user)? It may affect performance with big number I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it as follows,

```
findById(id:string):Observable<User[]>{
     return this.db.list('users',ref => 
     ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(id)).valueChanges();
}
```

and then inside the component,

```
var userlist = this.usersService.findById(value);
if (userlist) {
  userlist.forEach((val) => {

  });
}
```

and have a model as user.ts

```
export class User {
    id: string=null;
    name: string=null;
    ....
    etc
}
```